# Ramanujan Identity related to JacobiFunction

Tags: integration, modular-function

The following identity is allegedly due to Ramanujan
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{{\rm d}x}{(1+x^2)(1+r^2x^2)(1+r^4x^2)\cdots} = \frac{\pi/2}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}} \, $$but how do you prove this? The denominator of the right side is related to the Jacobi Function, so maybe one could proceed via modular forms?

Comment: The residue theorem and Jacobi triple product should lead to a simple answer.

Comment: Well I actually tried that, but somehow it didn't really help. What I had was $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-r^{2n})(1+r^n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n(n+1)/2} $$ by setting $x=r^{1/2}$ and $y=r^{1/4}$.

Comment: Using the residue theorem (after extending to $-\infty$) and closing above one obtains $$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm d}x}{\prod_{n=0}^\infty \left[1+(xr^n)^2\right]} = \pi i \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\rm Res} \frac{1}{\prod_{n=0}^\infty \left[1+(xr^n)^2\right]} \Bigg|_{x=\frac{i}{r^k}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^k} \prod_{\substack{n=0 \\ n\neq k}}^\infty \frac{1}{1-r^{2n-2k}} \, .$$

Comment: $$=\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^k} \left(\prod_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{1-r^{-2n}}\right) \left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-r^{2n}}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+r^n)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^{n(n+1)/2}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^k} \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{1-r^{-2n}} \, .$$ But how do I show that the product in the nominator and right sum cancel?

Comment: So essentially we have to prove the identity $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+r^n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{r^k} \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{1-r^{-2n}} \, .$$

Comment: Do you mean for the latter identity or for the original problem?

Comment: When expanding out the LHS I'll get $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m \sum_{\substack{n_1,n_2,n_3,\cdots=0 \\ n_1+2n_2+3n_3+\cdots=m}}^\infty (-1)^{n_1+n_2+\cdots}$$ and similarly expanding out the RHS gives $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty r^m \substack{\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \sum_{n_1,\cdots,n_k=0}^\infty 1 \\ k^2+2(n_1+2n_2+\cdots+kn_k)=m}$$ but I don't see a "trivial" way why the counting for the coefficients should be equal.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer for now. We have to prove that
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{1+r^n}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\prod_{n=1}^{k}\frac{r^{2n-1}}{r^{2n}-1} $$
or
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-r^n}{1-r^{2n}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k r^{k^2} \prod_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{1-r^{2n}} $$
or
$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}(1-r^n) = \sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k r^{k^2} \prod_{n>k}(1-r^{2n}) $$

where the LHS, by Euler's pentagonal number theorem, equals
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^k r^{k(3k-1)/2} $$
and the coefficient of $r^m$ in $\prod_{n>k}(1-r^n)$ depends on the number of partitions of $m$ into distinct parts with cardinality $>k$, accounted with a positive or negative sign according to the number of parts.

Now it shouldn't be difficult to prove our claim by using the same involution exploited in the [combinatorial proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) of Euler's pentagonal number theorem, or something quite close to it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort. Just some minor things: In the first formula it should be $r^{2n-1}$ instead of $r^{2n-k}$ if you pull it inside the product. In the second formula therefore it should be $r^{k^2}$ instead of $r^k$. I'll think about the rest.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/809863/72031).

Comment: Thank you. Interesting how the proper solution by math-fun is actually not the one accepted.